# Trouble with saving file onto expo filesystem. I get the uri for the recording but can't seem to get the file after leaving the screen

Tags: react-native, expo

So my problem is what the title says, and I have been stuck on this problem for over a week now and am at a loss for what I can do. Here's the code

I've tried many different methods but none seem to work, at least with the saving of the file. Please let me know if you need to see more code.

```
async _stopRecordingAndEnablePlayback() {
    this.setState({
      isLoadingz: true
    });
    try {
      await this.recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    } catch (error) {
    }
    const info = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(this.recording.getURI());
    console.log(
      `FILE INFO: ${JSON.stringify(info)}`,
      info.uri
    );
    const arr = [];
    const xFileInfo = JSON.stringify(info);
    arr.push(xFileInfo);
    this.setState({ fileInfo: arr, fileUri: info.uri });
    console.log(arr);
```